# When upgrading gradle with "./gradlew wrapper", no source and javadoc jar was downloaded, how to fix it?

Tags: gradle, javadoc, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

I need to debug a faulty gradle task that is triggered under `org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions`

The debugging will require source jar & javadoc jar to be downloaded for gradle-api.jar. However, when I try to download them with:

```
$./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.5.1
```

I only found the following files:

```
{home}/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-7.5.1.jar
{home}/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-kotlin-dsl-extensions-7.5.1.jar
{home}/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar
```

None of them has compatible source/javadoc file

How do I override this behaviour to facilitate debugging?